# Interpreting output of igraph's fastgreedy.community clustering method

Tags: clustering, networks, partitioning, igraph, modularity

With the help of several people in this community I have been wetting my feet in clustering some social network data using [igraph's implementation of modularity-based clustering](http://igraph.sourceforge.net/doc/R/fastgreedy.community.html).

I am having some trouble interpreting the output of this routine and how to use it to generate lists of members of each community detected.

This routine outputs a two-column matrix and a list of modularity values. From [the docs](http://igraph.sourceforge.net/doc/R/fastgreedy.community.html):

> merges: A matrix with two column, this
> represents a dendogram and contains
> all the merges the algorithm
> performed. Each line is one merge and
> it is given by the ids of the two
> communities merged. The community ids
> are integer numbers starting from zero
> and the communities between zero and
> the number of vertices (N) minus one
> belong to individual vertices. The
> first line of the matrix gives the
> first merge, this merge creates
> community N, the number of vertices,
> the second merge creates community
> N+1, etc.
>
> modularity:  A numeric vector
> containing the modularity value of the
> community structure after performing
> every merge.

Working with this explanation and looking at the example at the bottom of the man page, I think the communities in this graph are

```
1st community: 0 1 2 3 4
2nd community: 10 11 12 13 14
3rd community: 5 6 7 8 9
```

Can someone who has used this method before confirm whether the right approach produces this result? I have basically (i) ignored the last two merges and (ii) gone over each row in the 'merges' matrix, combining each pair of vertices into a set while watching out for vertex values that are larger than the number of vertices (and therefore refer to another row in the 'merges' matrix).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function which is used for this purpose:
  community.to.membership(graph, merges, steps, membership=TRUE, csize=TRUE)
this can be used to extract membership based on the fastgreedy.community function results.
You have to provide number of steps - how many merges should be performed. The optimal number of steps(merges) is the one which produce the maximal modularity.

Comment: @user1396: many thanks! I was thinking I had to do this 'by hand'. : ) I ran `community.to.membership(ag, z$merges, steps=12)` on the output of running `fastgreedy.community()` with the graph provided as an example in the docs and the output was `$membership
 [1] 2 2 2 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1

$csize
[1] 5 5 5`
I am confused by the repeated values in the $membership vector. How should I read them? I thought this would contain the vertice names. many thanks!

Comment: @user1396: I think I got it; a '2' in the i-th element in the membership vector is telling me the i-th vertex belongs to community 2. correct? :)